# Find a metric space that every subset has an empty boundary set

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

For this question I figured that we only need a space that all the subsets are both open and closed at the same time.
Besides the discrete space  does such a space exist?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be such a metric space. Now you want for every $A \subseteq X$ to have
$$\partial A = \overline A \setminus A^\circ = \emptyset.$$
As you noted this implies
$$\overline A  = A = A^\circ.$$
So every set is open. This implies that all subsets of $X$ belong to the topology, so we have the discrete topology which is induced by the discrete metric. Hence, $X$ is discrete.

Comment: Thank you. I have another question can the finite union of singleton sets work too as an example?

Comment: @AbuBakrAsi This is discrete! I just proved that this works if and only if the space is discrete.